# how to select from drop list and submit syntax

Tags: cakephp

i am a little new to the concept of using drop list box in cakephp.if a user selects the item and submits something.how can i out that item related to the slected item.
in my code below:module part should be submitted(added) in the correct module(selected from list box).can someone point out the syntax please.

controller code.

```
 $fields = array('id','moduleName');
   $modules = $this->Module->find('list',array('fields'=>$fields));
  $this->set(compact('modules'));

   if($this->request->is('post'))


{
    $mDetails = $this->Session->read('mDetails');
    $this->Modulepart->set('id', $mDetails['Modulepart']['id']);
    if($this->Modulepart->save($this->request->data)){
$this->Session->setFlash('Your new Module part has been successfully added!');
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'modules','action'=>'modules_home'));

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view (ModulePart/add.ctp) type this:

```
$this->Form->create('ModulePart');
$this->Form->input('ModulePart.module_id');
$this->Form->end('Add');
```

The auto-magic function will do the work for you just declaring the "modules" variable: the content, fetched with the list function (set for getting just the 'id' and the 'module_name' fields) will populate the form's select.

Please, be careful to the CakePHP conventions: your database field should be named 'module_name', not 'moduleName'. Regarding your model, you have to use this sintax

```
$this->ModulePart->save($this->request->data);
```

instead of

```
$this->Modulepart->save($this->request->data);
```

Remember: models name are Singular and Camel Cased. Controllers are Plurals and Camel Cased.

One more thing <= sound so much Steve-style, LOL => is about the code:

```
 $fields = array('id','moduleName');
 $modules = $this->Module->find('list',array('fields'=>$fields));
 $this->set(compact('modules'));
```

should be moved AFTER the request->is('post') check because of your redirect: if you add a ModulePart you don't need to fetch that data. There's a redirect to the modules_home after all...

Happy coding and read the CookBook ;)